# Executing python code(WITH MODULES) from a string

Tags: python

I got a very specific problem. I want to call a Python function inside a executed python script(from a python string) that contains imports in the beginning.

Sounds complicated, but it is not. What I want to do is this:

```
x = """import os
def test():
   print(os.curdir)
"""
exec(x)
test()
```

This works in the terminal(ipython and CPython), but it does not work inside an actual python script. It wont work because it says **os is not imported**, so I guess it is because the os is imported into a scope that is discarded, and when I call it from the script it does not have os imported.

I have other ways I could go around this annoying problem, but they all include writing the file to the harddrive(which is unacceptable in my script).

## UPDATE

Sorry, apparently this issue is only happening if you call exec and test from a function

example:

```
x = """import os
def test():
       print(os.curdir)
       """

def mytest():
    exec(x)
    test()
mytest()
```

The other one works apparently, which makes no sense at all for me.

Comment: I have no problems running this code on Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any problem with your code. I have tried it on both Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.2.3, on both Linux and Mac OS X.

Moreover, the following worked well:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

x = """import os
def test():
   print(os.curdir)
"""
exec(x)
test()
print (os.curdir)
```

Answer (score 0):

What Python Version are you using?
I don't know i it should not work. Exec executes it in the same global scope.
So if test is avail, os should be avail as well ;)

Comment: I use Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) compiled with GCC 4.8.2. (Standard Ubuntu Server Python in 14.04 LTS)